# how to start another application from my application in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
final List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

The above PackageInfo class for get the list of packages then

get package names for :

```
    ViewHendler hendler = new ViewHendler();
                hendler.textLable = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);



startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

then start applicathin using package name call :launchApp(packageName)

```
void launchApp(String packageName) {

        Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
       if (mIntent != null) {
            try {
                startActivity(mIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.app_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

But didn't get result(start another application from my application).

Comment: do you have the launcher permission set?

Comment: Please rename you launchApp to launchActivity. Because you are not launching an application! A service is also part of an 'application'...

Answer (score 1):

It's right way to use:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

But probably you have no permission, or you don't have application there.
Firstly check your `packageName` parameter.